# Stop SVG animation in the middle and move it's position

Tags: animation, svg

I found this question [Move an SVG object along a line or a path](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16216462/move-an-svg-object-along-a-line-or-a-path) but I need to move the object using a keyboard is it posible to freeze the animation along the path in one place, and change animation position somehow?

Answer (score 2):

You can call [pauseAnimations](http://www.w3.org/TR/SVG/struct.html#__svg__SVGSVGElement__pauseAnimations) to freeze all animations. You could then modify the animation element attributes using [element.setAttribute](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/element.setAttribute) as you wish.